# How to concat 2 sliced array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, concatenation

I have:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and I'm trying to do:

```
var b = [];
b.concat(a.slice(0,3), a.slice(-3))
```

And as a result I have:

```
b == []
```

How I can get 3 first and 3 last elements from an array at `b`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) doesn't work inline on the array. The result of `concat()` has to be catched.

> The `concat()` method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

You're not updating the value of `b` array.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var b = [].concat(a.slice(0, 3), a.slice(-3));

document.write(b);
console.log(b);
```

You can also `concat` the sliced arrays.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var b = a.slice(0, 3).concat(a.slice(-3));

document.write(b);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) has no side effects, meaning it does not modify the original array (i.e. `b`)

I see two ways of achieving what you want:

Assigning the result of `concat` to `b` (it will break the reference to the original array, since it is a fresh new one)

```
b = b.concat(a.slice(0,3), a.slice(-3));
```

Or using [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and `apply` to modify `b` in place

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(b, a.slice(0,3).concat(a.slice(-3)));
```

This one is a bit tricky. Why would you use `apply`?

Because doing `b.push(a.slice(0, 3), a.slice(0 - 3))` would have resulted in a different structure: `[[...], [...]]`

For more information about `apply` see the documentation for [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you. Some of the older JS array functions are very silly. They don't return what you want just like `push()` which returns the length of the resulting array instead of returning a reference to the resulting array. There have been times i want to delete an item and pass the resulting array as an argument to a function at the same time. That's where your question walks in. I have an array

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

and i want to delete item 5 and pass the array as an argument. Assume `i` is 4.

```
myRecursiveFunction(arr.splice(i,1));
```

won't cut. The silly thing will pass the deleted element in an array to the function instead of a reference to the array called upon. But i don't want to do several instructions. I just want to pass it to a function as a single instruction's return value. So i have to come up with inventions like.

```
myRecursiveFunction(arr.slice(0,i).concat(arr.slice(i+1)));
```

Anybody with a better idea please let me know.